# Corpus of words divided by language

Tags: data-request, language, global, corpora, dictionary

I am looking for a word dataset composed by lists of words of multiple languages (possibly all the major languages), non topic specific, divided by language.

I don't really care for translations, meanings, alternative forms, pronunciation or anything else. However, I would need an offline dataset.

Do you know if any such dataset exist?

ps: I have seen the Multilingual Wordnet site at http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/ however it is missing some important languages like German, Russian and Korean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just interested in words (and not translations) you can check out [Wortschatz](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en) at Universität Leipzig.

An alternative (with very different coverage across languages, but actually providing translations) is the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page).

Comment: Thanks the list of words from Wortschatz are exactly what I wanted, few extra information and easily parseable

Comment: There are also python bindings for their website available at https://github.com/lehmannro/libleipzig-python

Answer (score 1):

Consider wikidata. Wikidata is a site that linked all different articles from different wikipedia together, as such article name of these wikipedia articles would form a list of word for each language that might be suitable for your list.

Wikidata database can be downloaded from https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download